# How to pass a variable inside a function?

Tags: php

I am using a API 
and passing a variable to the API's function but its working in this case:
curl_init('https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid=123456');

I want to pass **txid** value by a variable , I try my best but above function is not working by following ways:

```
$value="https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid=".$txnid;

        curl_init($value); 

    curl_init('https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid=$txnid'); 
    curl_init('https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid='$txnid''); 
    curl_init("https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid='".$txnid."'"); 
    curl_init("https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid=$txnid");
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: `$value="https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid=".$txnid;` this seems fine. what is the error that you got

Comment: curl_init("https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php?txid=$txnid");  should technically work

Comment: I mean if we write txid=12345 then its working , but if i pass e.g 12345 by variable $txnid ,then curl_init() not working

Comment: @Jazba show your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

when i fire above api  url using browser
   it show error

```
API requests can only be made via POST. For documentation see: https://www.coinpayments.net/apidoc
```

so you have to pass variable as a post parameter using below code

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{'txn_id':".$txn_id."}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

i got response from above url when i use above code

```
{
   "error": "No HMAC signature sent",
   "result": []
}
```